# Python 3 Nested Functions Variable

Tags: function, python-3.x, nested

```
def main_function():
    variable = blur.copy() #copy of a blurred image that is defined in main_function

    def sub_function():
            global res
            variable = a_library_function(variable, other parameters)
    sub_function()
main_function()
```

When i try to run the code, ıt returns "name 'variable' is not defined". It works well without main_function. I do that because there are many sub_functions and i want to call all of them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `variable` as `nonlocal` in four sub function:

```
def sub_function():
    nonlocal variable
```

Comment: Great. You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.